# get_template_part() with underscore from core folder

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming, themes, parent-child

I need a child copy of `listings_recently.php` file to make changes on it. I need to include this file into my child theme: `/themes/listingeasy/core/widgets/listings_recently.php`

As far as I know, I need to tell the theme to look for that file. And that's made in my childs theme `functions.php` right?

So this is my `functions.php`:

```
get_template_part('get_stylesheet_directory() . "/core/widgets/listings"', 'recently');
get_template_part('get_stylesheet_directory() . "/core/widgets/listings_recently.php"');
```

Not working none of the 2 lines.

How do I need to proceed? Here is folder schema:

```
themes
    listingeasy
        single.php
        core
            widgets
                listing_recently.php
    listingeasy-child
        functions.php
        single.php (I made changes here and its working)
        core
            widgets
                listing_recently.php (Changes here aren't working)
```

Comment: Do you plan to use this code in other places?  Generally you would not use this function to add things to functions.php, you would use require().  get_template_part is more frequently used when applying pieces of code to multiple other page templates, or when using in multiple places, so you don't have to rewrite code each time. I'm a little confused at what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Where is this file located? /themes/listingeasy/core/widgets/listings_recently.php
Is it in child theme or parent thene or other theme?

Comment: @Sagar Bahadur Tamang, I've edited the question with the folder schema in case it helps.

Comment: @Dubvader I've edited the question with the folder schema in case it helps. I want to make changes on my theme. The file I need to modify is `listings_recently.php` but changes aren't taking into account.

Comment: @Flowen I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961370/how-to-override-a-widget-in-a-child-theme-in-wordpress

Comment: @KalimahApps I did all explained in there and still not working. PHP is not giving me the error since I changed the class name but changes are not taking into account. Feels like the file which is taking into account is the parent one always.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know your theme. But when you want to edit the functions in listings_recently.php, then you can try to copy these functions to your child-themes functions.php and edit them there. Most of the time it works.

Regards Tom

**Edit:** try require(); in your child themes functions.php:

```
require('core/widgets/listings_recently.php');
```

**Edit 2** (see comment, the theme itself has its own get_template_directory())

```
get_template_directory()
```

returns the path to your parent template directory. Use

```
get_stylesheet_directory()
```

to return the path of your child-themes directory

Comment: Hi Tom. I'm not trying to edit a function. I'm trying to make a copy of the `listings_recently.php` file to my child theme, so I can make custom modifications. The thing is, once copied, I need to specify  that I'm using that file, and I don't know how exactly because it has an underscore and its not working apparently.

Comment: Not working. The theme itself has his own `require_once(get_template_directory() . "/core/widgets/listings_recently.php");` I'm editing the question since I've tried more things.

Comment: get_template_directory() returns the path to your parent template directory. Use get_stylesheet_directory() to return the path of you child-themes directory

Answer (score 0):

I created a child theme of the twentyninteeen theme to reproduce your scenario. The folder structure of the child theme is like this.

[image: Folder Structure]

> functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

get_template_part( 'core/widgets/listings_recently' );
```

> listings_recently.php

```
<h1>Sagar Tamang</h1>;

<?php
```

You need to use `get_template_part( 'core/widgets/listings_recently' );` to include files with underscore. If you have used the `get_template_part()` function in the functions.php, the output seems to be above the HTML tag.

[image]

Comment: This isn't working for me. I edited the question with the folder schema in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I see now what you're trying to do here.  It appears you are trying to add a copy of the file to your child theme, so that you can edit that file, and have those changes overwrite the parent, without changing the parent theme's file.  **This is not a natively supported action on arbitrary php files, only on theme template files**.

You need to move it in to the primary theme directory, same as where single.php is, and give it an appropriate theme hierarchy filename.  That is why your changes for single.php file work, and for this particular file do not.  Single.php is a known template, your file is just a php file you added.

Alternatively, you can make changes to your listings_recently.php file, and replace the current version in the parent theme.  If you're worried about losing the old version, save it to your desktop or use a version control system like GitHub.  This is probably the best way to do it.

Third option is to make hard coded changes to the functions.php file of the child theme.